# Getting an error from Entity Framework(type initializer exception)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I' am getting this:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

error in my Entity Framework.

I read this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585611/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except) and the possible answers, however non of them worked for me. Here is my App.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SalesReportEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/SalesReportModel.csdl
                         |res://*/SalesReportModel.ssdl
                         |res://*/SalesReportModel.msl;
                         provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                         provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;
                                                    initial catalog=Training;
                                                    integrated security=True;
                                                    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
                                                    App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework> 
</configuration>
```

What other possible things can cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can offer a few suggestions and some are similar to the thread you already looked at:

1. Can you use SQL Management Studio and verify this database exists and has tables and is currently in a responsive state?
2. Put your 'connectionStrings' section after the < providers > node.
3. Your parameter value is 'v11.0' which seems to be targeting a version of SQL Server 2012.  Mine that I am looking at now is similar to yours but just states: "mssqllocaldb".  Which I believe is just the default instance of sql server from the connection you specify.
4. Uninstall Entity Framework completely and get it again from NuGet.  I assume you are using Visual Studio so in 2015 it is Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Packages.  Uninstall, check your app config and 'References' that 'EntityFramework' is gone.  Reinstall and check your settings again.
5. Are you trying to reference a project that entity lives in in another project or is it self contained?  If so you need to target EF just like you were on the source project with adding EF to that project and a config the same.

You may also want to post the entire exception for better answers too.

Comment: Actually you are right ! This issue is related with 4th one that you mentioned(I mean in my situation). I uninstalled and reinstalled again, and also I realized that i did not manage my Entity Framework correctly in the first one. Again, thanks a lot !

Comment: No prob, good luck with EF6.  It is very useful in combination with Linq and understanding how it works is half the battle.