# How to fix "Activated Event Time Duration Thread Exception" in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

> ERROR:
>   Activated   Event   Time    Duration    Thread
>       Exception: Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in EntityFramework.dll ("The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception."). Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in EntityFramework.dll ("The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.")

Comment: Not enough to give an opinion. please edit your post with the scenario details when you face this exception. As you are new, please do not provide sensitive information, such as password or private key or database address when you edit this.

Comment: Please check this article before asking a question o SO : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: it looks like your EF install could have been corrupted try repairing the install from nuget

Comment: What you need guidance for guidance???@Md.TazbirUrRahmanBhuiyan

Comment: @esmaeil Code where it's being thrown could be a start

Comment: @MikeT
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: as i said uninstalling and reinstalling the framework, i would suggest using the Nuget gui built into Visual studio, however the commands are `Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -RemoveDependencies` `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0`

Comment: @Fourat My question is standard . This problem is not related to the Syntax code . It is the fault of system files . But I don't know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: @Fourat this error is as connections by Entity framework My system.

Comment: @MikeT 

I did your proposed solution, but the problem was not solved.

Do you have another solution?

Comment: then you need to give more details, when does the error occur, is it associated with a certain line of code, have you got the valid entries in your config?

Comment: try having a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585611/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except they are getting the same error but gave enough detail that someone could answer them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps s for solving my problem:

1.I removed EntityFramework 6.2.0 and installed it again.

2.I deleted ModelData Base and added to project it again.

With this solution, my problem solved.