# Not able to enable migrations through Nuget Package Manager

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, migration, code-first

I am trying `enable-migrations` in console but getting this error.
I am getting this error, please help anyone.

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.
```

This is my program.cs file

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class BlogDbContext : DbContext
{
    public Dbset<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use static class or static variable in your code ?

Comment: See my code above, this is my main file

Comment: What is EF version, that you use?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585611/the-type-initializer-for-system-data-entity-internal-appconfig-threw-an-except)

Comment: my version of EF is 6.4.4

Comment: Did you try this solution ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19735839/8810311

Comment: yes, but it's not working

Comment: this issue is still not resolved

Comment: Is this in VS 2010? If so please use the community edition of VS 2019 It will have everything you need, but is of course free), 2010 is so far back in time I would suggest that all sorts of SDKs and dependencies could be very far out of date.

Comment: no sir, It is VS 2019.